# Reuse code memory for data

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, ld

I have some C-code that run on a system with limited amount of memory.
The code execution have basically two phases, startup phase and main phase.
The startup phase consist of code that generates some parameters used by the main phase. During the main phase data is generated.

Since the startup phase is run only once I would like to reuse the memory space used by the startup code for data storage in the main phase.

I have tested one way to handle this:

- A custom linker script placing code and data associated with the startup phase in a .startup section. This section is placed on the same address as .bss that is the bss section used by the main phase. 
  The startup code calls the entry point for the startup phase and when
  it returns, before calling main in the main phase, it clears the .bss section.
  Xrossref commands is used in linker script to help getting code and data into right place.

This works but it has it's quirks. To get the startup code and data in the .startup section I must list them with input section names given by gcc during compilation.

Now I would like to enable lto (link time optimization) and that breaks the above method since input section names are changed.

Thinking of testing a new approach:

- Build startup code and main code as two separate programs. Each program is build and optimized separately and put together to one boot image.
  Advantage is that there is no risk that the main code calls a function accidentally placed in startup section (which does no longer exist when main code is executed). Another advantage is that I do only need to specify the entry point for each phase and the linker will do the rest of finding out code and data needed for that phase.
  The parameter data output from startup and used by main can be placed in a common bss section or on the stack.

Disadvantage is that I can not see how startup code and main code can share functions that are used in both phases. If the shared functions are small, trying to share them might be a bad idea since lto will be more restricted or end up inlineing two versions of the shared function anyway.

Does anyone know of a preferred method for this or have any comment on the new suggested approach?

Comment: The original playstation console could do this with "overlays" like DLL's but they sort of rebase in your address space. So sometimes funcA() would be a stub, and sometimes it would be a full function

Comment: You second approach is known as `Two-Stage Bootloader`. It is widely used on TI boards. Don't try to make shared functions resident for startup and main code. Think as they are different (for example runtime address for `memcpy` for `startup` code could be at different address for `main` code). And for passing data from `startup` to `main` code you should declare struct, place it at some memory location (known for both codes).

Comment: Rewrite the startup phase to not use any variables of static storage duration; or if this is unavoiable you could perhaps make a union rather than doing a build system hack.

Comment: Also can you clarify whether you are referring to static variables or something else, some of your sentences sound as if you are talking about the storage used for the actual program code itself

Comment: I'm talking about reusing the memory space holding the startup code for storage of data during the main phase.

Comment: Along @MattMcNabb 's point, assuming the code is somewhere (like in ROM) to be loaded in, is there anyway you could execute that directly?  That would also save the load time.

Answer (score 1):

The method I've seen (Rabbit processors) is using overlays. [There was some hardware involved, so I'm not sure the analogy is perfect.]  Anyway, the notion [in my mind] is like an elevator.  You have a small amount of program space (the elevator cage) which is safe and viable at all times.  But if you want to access another 'floor', you go back to the elevator (PC is in that small address space) and then switch the settings to activate another bank of memory.  Then you can exit the elevator and be on a new floor.

You have a slightly different issue (want to use less memory instead of not having enough address lines) but the same strategy could apply.

Start in the elevator.  Run the first start up code, which sets certain data values, also presumably in a safe area.  Retreat back to the elevator.  Overwrite the startup code space.  Now you can exit the elevator.  But you will still need the addresses of the new space.  These need to be stored somewhere.  Perhaps you have two sets of function pointers, with overlapping addresses, one for use in the startup, and another for use in the main code.  Just use the right functions at the right time.